# Thumbnails for MP3s are missing in explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp3, thumbnails

I just set up Windows 10 on my PC and everything works great except one glitch.

I have a folder with many MP3s which contain a picture in the MP3-tag. On Windows 7 I used to see this picture in the explorer for every item.

Now on Windows 10 I just see the Winamp icon, no matter on what icon size I set the folder.

I googled around but nothing seems to work/change anything. I tried to activate thumbs via System performance settings and global folder settings. No effect.

Comment: Is it only thumbnails for MP3 files that are missing? If you open your Pictures folder, do you see thumbnails there?

Comment: @FastEthernet: Yes, only MP3s. Pictures are just they are supposed to be.